# Obtain an inequality of real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $x,y> 0$ be real numbers such that $x>y$. Let $\alpha \in (0,1/2)$ be a parameter then I obtained the following inequality:
$$y^{-\alpha} - x^{-\alpha} \leq C y^{-\alpha-\gamma}(x-y)^\gamma$$
for every $\gamma<\frac{1}{2}-\alpha$ for some constant $C>0$ independent of the variables involved.

Can this inequality be improved? I want to obtain the factor $(x-y)$ on the right hand side but I wonder if the factor $y^{-\alpha-\gamma}$ could be improved.

Any ideas on how to obtain inequalities for $y^{-\alpha} - x^{-\alpha}$ involving $(x-y)$ with some positive power?

Thanks a lot!!